# Any library can parse Formdata (support multipart and urlencoded) in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, package

> Hello everyone, I'm a stackoverflow novice.
>
> If I have any problem about asking this question, hope to redress me.
>   :)

---

1. Encryption of posting form is `(default - application/x-www-form-urlencoded)`.

   I used ['body-parser'](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).
2. Encryption of posting form with files is `(multipart/form-data)`.

   I used ['node-formidable'](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

But two of above are different that coding style.

I wanna unify the style to write code about form parser.

Is there any package that can support exist?

---

Thanks everyone :)